# manipulating the list based on custom logic

Tags: python, list

I have a lists of list where it consists of hour,day and total number of clicks. I need to separate the list into day wise for all the hours.

For example, below is the list. The list contains a tuple and an element. The tuple represents hour and a day and the other element represents the number of clicks. Here, [(0,1),3] --> in (0,1) , 0 represents hour and 1 represents day. 3 represents the number of clicks. Like this I have for all 24 hours ranges from 0 to 23 for 31 days.

```
[[(0, 1), 1],
 [(0, 2), 3],
 [(0, 3), 19],
 [(0, 4), 1],
 [(0, 5), 3],
 [(0, 6), 1],
 [(0, 8), 6],
 [(0, 11), 1],
 [(0, 12), 36],
 [(0, 15), 1],
 [(0, 16), 1],
 [(0, 20), 56],
 [(0, 21), 4],
 [(0, 22), 1],
 [(0, 24), 4],
 [(0, 25), 2],
 [(0, 26), 3],
 [(0, 27), 18],
 [(0, 28), 25],
 [(0, 30), 4],
 [(1, 1), 12],
 [(1, 2), 2],
 [(1, 3), 9],
 [(1, 4), 1],
 [(1, 5), 15],
 [(1, 6), 4],
 [(1, 7), 6],
 [(1, 8), 13],
 [(1, 10), 3],
 [(1, 11), 14],
 [(1, 12), 2],
 [(1, 13), 9],
 [(1, 14), 3],
 [(1, 15), 10],
 [(1, 16), 6],
 [(1, 18), 2],
 [(1, 19), 7],
 [(1, 20), 3],
 [(1, 21), 2],
 [(1, 22), 1],
 [(1, 23), 1],
 [(1, 24), 1],
 [(1, 25), 3],
 [(1, 26), 1],
 [(1, 27), 2],
 [(1, 28), 13],
 [(1, 29), 10]]
```

I need to create a dataframe per day per hour basis. If there is no hour on that particular day it should be given 0 for total_clicks.

```
day hour total_clicks
1   0      3
1   1      5
1   2      8
2   0      10
2   1      7
2   2      6
```

Can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: you want it in the most efficient way or u dont care abt complexity

Comment: no need of complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this for you. This will get a full day and hour frame and fill the missing be 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

This is the test data.

```
test_data = [
    [(0, 1), 1],
    [(0, 2), 3],
    [(0, 3), 19],
    [(0, 4), 1],
    [(0, 5), 3],
    [(0, 6), 1],
    [(0, 8), 6],
    [(0, 11), 1],
    [(0, 12), 36],
    [(0, 15), 1],
    [(0, 16), 1],
    [(0, 20), 56],
    [(0, 21), 4],
    [(0, 22), 1],
    [(0, 24), 4],
    [(0, 25), 2],
    [(0, 26), 3],
    [(0, 27), 18],
    [(0, 28), 25],
    [(0, 30), 4],
    [(1, 1), 12],
    [(1, 2), 2],
    [(1, 3), 9],
    [(1, 4), 1],
    [(1, 5), 15],
    [(1, 6), 4],
    [(1, 7), 6],
    [(1, 8), 13],
    [(1, 10), 3],
    [(1, 11), 14],
    [(1, 12), 2],
    [(1, 13), 9],
    [(1, 14), 3],
    [(1, 15), 10],
    [(1, 16), 6],
    [(1, 18), 2],
    [(1, 19), 7],
    [(1, 20), 3],
    [(1, 21), 2],
    [(1, 22), 1],
    [(1, 23), 1],
    [(1, 24), 1],
    [(1, 25), 3],
    [(1, 26), 1],
    [(1, 27), 2],
    [(1, 28), 13],
    [(1, 29), 10],
]
```

This is the code:

```
formatted_test_data = [[row[0][0], row[0][1], row[1]] for row in test_data]
df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_test_data, columns=["hour", "day", "total_clicks"])
min_day = df["day"].min()
max_day = df["day"].max()
frame_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": np.repeat(np.arange(min_day, max_day + 1), 24),
        "hour": np.repeat(
            np.arange(24).reshape(1, -1), max_day - min_day + 1, axis=0
        ).flatten(),
    }
)
result = frame_df.merge(
    df.groupby(["day", "hour"]).sum().reset_index(), on=["day", "hour"], how="left"
).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the optimised code. Awesome work

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do.

I have highlighted 2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_list,columns=['day_hour','clicks'])

#1 
df[['day', 'hour']] = pd.DataFrame(df['day_hour'].tolist(),index=df.index)
#2 
df['day'], df['hour'] = df['day_hour'].str
```

Comment: still missing the part where if an hour doesnt exist it gives 0 clicks